# How to modify a reg_expand_sz value from command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to edit an existing registry key from a .reg file. I want to change the vaue of the key, which is a reg_expand_sz value to a different one (the value is a file path). I tried doing it like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

["HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors"]
"Arrow"=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"%SystemRoot%\System32\VIRUS\Virus\newArrow.cur"
```

Which didn't work. What should I do instead?

Comment: What have you tried, what was the (unexpected) result, what error message did you get? How did you tried to edit? Where is your script? Please explain!

Comment: The above code was saved in a .reg file. Not sure what you mean by script, this is the extent of the code. I want to change the file path of the key named "Arrow" from "%SystemRoot%\cursors\aero_arrow.cur" to "%SystemRoot%\System32\VIRUS\Virus\newArrow.cur". When I run the .reg file, it says the keys and values have successfully been added to the registry, but the value of the key remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like windows (7) is accepting values as hex in there.
Easiest way to understand it is to edit it manually, and then make an export inside regedit application. Will show you what to do.

I did it and got this and it works.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors]
"Arrow"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,56,00,\
  49,00,52,00,55,00,53,00,5c,00,56,00,69,00,72,00,75,00,73,00,5c,00,6e,00,65,\
  00,77,00,41,00,72,00,72,00,6f,00,77,00,2e,00,63,00,75,00,72,00,00,00
```

Comment: You welcome, please don't forget the simpliest aproach. Edit it manually and just take an export from regedit.
Also note this application to make thing easier with reg files: http://ctuser.net/?reg2exe

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell

```c
sp 'hkcu:control panel/cursors' arrow `
  '%SystemRoot%/System32/VIRUS/Virus/newArrow.cur'
```

[`Set-ItemProperty`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849844)

Answer (score 1):

**REG_SZ** : A null-terminated string. This will be either a Unicode or an ANSI string, depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions.

**REG_EXPAND_SZ** : A null-terminated string that contains unexpanded references to environment variables (for example, "%PATH%"). It will be a Unicode or ANSI string depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions. To expand the environment variable references, use the Expand EnvironmentStrings function

Ex : C:\ (%HomeDrive%)

**REG_SZ** : @="C:\"

**REG_EXPAND_SZ** : @=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,00,00

So, You must use **REG_EXPAND_SZ** for A null-terminated string that contains unexpanded references to environment variables (for example %HomeDrive% , %App% , %SystemRoot% ... ).

Answer (score 1):

With powershell is tricky to avoid the expansion of the variables. The solution I am using, calling [RegistryKey.GetValue Method (String, Object, RegistryValueOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzxd58z1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a bit verbose, but its rationale is well described in https://www.sepago.com/blog/2013/08/22/reading-and-writing-regexpandsz-data-with-powershell

```
$Hive = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine
$keypath='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems'
$Key = $Hive.OpenSubKey($keypath, $True)

# prevent expansion
$oldValue = $Key.GetValue($valueName, $False, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)

# update the value
$newValue = $oldValue -replace '(^.*SharedSection=\d+,\d+),(\d+) (.*$)', "`$1,$newHeap `$3"
$Key.SetValue($valueName, $newValue, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
```